# Why doesn't this "undefined extern variable" result in a linker error in C++17?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, extern, c++17, if-constexpr

I have compiled and ran the following program in a C++17 compiler (Coliru). In the program, I **declared** an `extern` variable, but **did not define** it. However, the compiler doesn't give a **linker error**.

```
#include <iostream>

extern int i; // Only declaration

int func() 
{
    if constexpr (true)
        return 0;
    else if (i)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main() 
{
    int ret = func();
    std::cout<<"Ret : "<<ret<<std::endl;
}
```

**Why doesn't the compiler give a linker error?**

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Because the variable isn't odr-used. You have a `constexpr if` there that always discards the branch that could use it.

One of the points of `constexpr if` is that the discarded branch need not even compile, only be well-formed. That's how we can place calls to non-existing member functions in a discarded branch.

Comment: If I change the `constexpr if` to a normal `if`, then I also won't get a linker error. Why?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Aggressive optimization and non-standard, I think. It doesn't  link when the optimizer has no choice but to refer to the variable http://ideone.com/NjEqoy

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Actually clang and GCC both just accepted it for me. I'm stumped.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - AnT has the quote in their answer. No diagnostic required.

Comment: I think that GCC and clang treat an external declaration as a weak definition, for compatibility with old non-standard code.

Answer (score 41):

In your case the variable is used in discarded statements only. However, even if we ignore that fact, C++ language specification still explicitly states that *no diagnostic is required* for missing definitions

> **3.2 One-definition rule**
>
> **4** Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement (6.4.1); **no diagnostic required**.

The language specification understands that an optimizing compiler might be smart enough to eliminate all odr-uses of a variable. In that case it would be excessive and unnecessary to require the implementation to detect and report the potential ODR violations.

Comment: Even if there is no diagnostic required, doesn't it still mean the program is ill formed and thus shouldn't pass compilation & linking?

Comment: @Rick Astley: "Ill-formed" never meant "shouldn't pass compilation & linking". Implementations are allowed to "successfully" compile absolutely anything, as long as they issued diagnostics where diagnostics is required by the language specification. In fact, the only feature that is required to actually *terminate* compilation in C++ is `#error` directive.

Comment: @AnT: Almost correct, except that the compiler does not even have to stop processing after `#error`, it is *only*  required to issue a diagnostic, and the program is ill-formed (whereas `#warning` does not render the program ill-formed). See §16.5 [N4140, cpp.error]. (Update: `#warning` is not part of the standard.)

Comment: There's also `static_assert`, not that it matters.

Comment: @Deduplicator `static_assert(!"do not format harddrive");` can produce an executable that formats the hard drive.  It must also generate a diagnostic, but the standard places zero restriction on what a compiler does with an ill-formed program.  Not that this matters, as only a hostile compiler is likely to do that.

Answer (score 9):

Because the compiler produces compiler errors, the **linker** would yield linker errors ...

No, seriously:

```
if constexpr (true)
```

is always true, so the compiler ignores the rest of the if-clause because it is never reached. So `i` is never used actually.

Answer (score 1):

This has alrady been answered, but if you are interested, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) has exactly this example for *constexpr if*:

> #### Constexpr If
>
> The statement that begins with `if constexpr` is known as the *constexpr if statement*.
>
> In a constexpr if statement, the value of *condition* must be a contextually converted [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) of type bool. If the value is true, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.
> [...]
> The discarded statement can [odr-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) a variable that is not defined:

```
extern int x; // no definition of x required
int f() {
if constexpr (true)
    return 0;
else if (x)
    return x;
else
    return -x;
}
```